# Broken aggregation in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm getting erroneous results on performing terms aggregation in the field `names` in the index. 
The following is the mappings I have used to the `names` field:

```
{
  "dbnames": {
    "properties": {
      "names": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the results I'm getting for a simple `terms` aggregation on the field:

```
"aggregations": {
  "names": {
    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
    "buckets": [
      {
        "key": "John Martin",
        "doc_count": 1
      },
      {
        "key": "John martin",
        "doc_count": 1
      },
      {
        "key": " Victor Moses",
        "doc_count": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see, I have the same names with different casings being shown as different buckets in the aggregation. What I want here is irrespective of the case, the names should be clubbed together.

Comment: what way should they be grouped? under `John Martin` or `John martin` or something else e.g. lowercased `john martin`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to make sure you properly case the value of your `names` field at indexing time.

If that is not an option, the other way to go about it is to define an analyzer that will do it for you and set that analyzer as `index_analyzer` for the `names` field. Such a custom analyzer would need to use the [`keyword` tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/analysis-keyword-tokenizer.html) (i.e. take the whole value of the field as a single token)  and the [`lowercase` token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html) (i.e. lowercase the value)

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/your_index -d '{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "casing": {               <--- custom casing analyzer
            "filter": [
              "lowercase"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "your_type": {
      "properties": {
        "names": {
          "type": "string",
          "index_analyzer": "casing"      <--- use your custom analyzer
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Then we can index some data:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/_bulk -d '
{"index":{}}
{"names": "John Martin"}
{"index":{}}
{"names": "John martin"}
{"index":{}}
{"names": "Victor Moses"}
'
```

And finally the `terms` aggregation on the `names` field would return your the expected results:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/_search-d '{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "dbnames": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "names"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Results:

```
{
  "dbnames": {
    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
    "buckets": [
      {
        "key": "john martin",
        "doc_count": 2
      },
      {
        "key": "victor moses",
        "doc_count": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 options here

1. Use not_analyzed option - This one has a disadvantage that same
   string with different cases wont be seen as on
2. keyword tokenizer + lowercase filter - This one does not have the
   above issue

I have neatly outlined these two approaches and how to use them here - https://qbox.io/blog/elasticsearch-aggregation-custom-analyzer